# remove gesture for UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm using `UIGestureRecognizer` for pan, rotate, pinch. But i'm applying to whole view. I need to remove gesture for button other than subviews. But when i use pan the button also affecting. How to restrict button move from self.view. I used below code for `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *dbpan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                        action:@selector(ondbPan:)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:dbpan];

[closeButton removeGestureRecognizer:dbpan];
```

Pan:

```
- (void)ondbPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
        (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {


        CGPoint offset = [gesture translationInView:self.view];

        CGPoint center = gesture.view.center;
        center.x += offset.x;
        center.y += offset.y;
        gesture.view.center = center;

        [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with bellow code that delegate of `UIGestureRecognizer` return FALSE if that subview is kind of class UIButton Class. also set delegate `dbpan.delegate = self;` while you setting and add `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
      if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
      {
           return FALSE;
      }
      else
      {

         return TRUE;
      }
}
```

**UPDATE:-**

I dont Know why that not working at your end i test this creating one demo as well using this code:-

**.h file**

```
@interface myviewcontroller : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

**and .m class**

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
        (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {

        CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self.view];

        [demoView setCenter:location];
    }
}

- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {

        return TRUE;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    UIPanGestureRecognizer *dbpan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                            action:@selector(pan:)];
    dbpan.delegate=self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:dbpan];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(IBAction)B1called
{

    NSLog(@"This is called button 1");

}
-(IBAction)B2called
{
     NSLog(@"This is called button 2");

}
```

And it's Output is

[image]

Comment: It's not working for me. Can you check my updated code for Pan?

Answer (score 1):

**On Swift:**

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

```
if (touch.view!.isKindOfClass(UIButton)) {
    return false
}
return true
}
```

Note: Make sure UIGestureRecognizerDelegate is added and tapGesture.delegate = self on viewDidLoad().

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
while (closeButton.gestureRecognizers.count) {
    [closeButton removeGestureRecognizer:[closeButton.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```